# perform lm() inside a piped (%>%) flow: Error of invalid term in model formula

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, lm

I intend to perform separate regression by each level of a factor in a data.frame.  I used to be able to do it by using `plyr::ddply` .  However, when I tried to use the pipe flow of analysis, I encountered the following errors.  Please advise how to overcome it, or I will have to revert to `plyr::ddply` , etc.  Thanks.

```
d = data.frame(
Gender = c("M","F"),
Age = rnorm(20, mean = 40, sd = 3),
Weight = rnorm(20, mean=70, sd=5)
)


fit <- d %>% group_by(Gender) %>%
summarise(
  Intercept = coef(lm(Weight ~ Age))[1],
  Slope = coef(lm(Weight ~ Age))[2]
)
```

> Error: invalid term in model formula

Comment: Also, for a complex model, it would be nice to only run the regression once.  How to accomplish it in such a piped flow?

Comment: Try `do` instead of `summarise`.

Comment: Thanks to coffeinjunky for advice on best practices.  I have marked the answer of my preference, but both worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `do` will help and the model(s) will be calculated only once:

```
fit <- d %>% group_by(Gender) %>% 
       do(model = lm(Weight ~ Age, data=.)) %>% 
       mutate(Intercept=coef(model)[1], Slope=coef(model)[2]) %>%
       select(-model)
```

omit the last `select(-model)` to keep your `lm` models within their own column.

Answer (score 6):

An easier solution would even be to use `broom`. `broom::tidy` rearranges model-output into nice and clean dataframes, and you don't have to access individual coefficients manually. For more information, see `vignette(broom)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

fit <- d %>% group_by(Gender) %>% do(data.frame(tidy(lm(Weight ~ Age, data=.))))
fit
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: Gender [2]

  Gender        term   estimate  std.error  statistic     p.value
  (fctr)       (chr)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)       (dbl)
1      F (Intercept) 92.5751034 37.6736331  2.4572916 0.039485169
2      F         Age -0.5132374  0.9098960 -0.5640616 0.588172020
3      M (Intercept) 41.4985927 10.4958042  3.9538269 0.004213341
4      M         Age  0.7346306  0.2691001  2.7299529 0.025847680
```

Here, the model output is stored according to the grouping variable, and each coefficient is stored in an individual row, which you can easily subset.

Comment: Just a question about the pipe here. Why do you mix piping with traditional `function1(function2(function3(x)))` styles? Is it not possible to pipe it all the way through?

Comment: Good question. The way I understand it is that `do` is similar to `summarise` or `mutate`, where you also use the traditional function calls. For instance, you would not write `group_by(Gender) %>% mean(var) %>% summarise`, instead of `group_by(Gender) %>% summarise(mean(var))`.